# Caption centered with the page and not the table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have this table and I want the caption to be aligned with the table and not on the center of the page. Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{c||c}
      Sistema       & $\delta W_{rev}$                   \\\hline\hline
      Hidrostático  & $-PdV$                             \\
      Elástico 1D   & $\tau dL$                          \\
      Laminas       & $\sigma dA$                        \\
      Dieléctricos  & $Ed\vec{P}$                        \\
      Paramagnético & $\underbrace{\mu_0H}_{B_0}\vec{M}$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Trabajo reversible en diferentes sistemas}
\end{table}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

How do I center the caption with the table? I want the table to be in that position but the caption aligned with the table, I don't want to move the table.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

The following first typesets your `tabular` into a box, then adjusts the width the `\caption` might take (by using it inside a `minipage`) to be just as wide as the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\tabularcaptionbox
\newenvironment{tabularcaption}[1]
  {%
    \edef\tabularcaptioncaption{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \begin{lrbox}\tabularcaptionbox
  }
  {%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\wd\tabularcaptionbox}%
      \usebox\tabularcaptionbox
      \caption{\tabularcaptioncaption}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularcaption}{Trabajo reversible en diferentes sistemas}%
    \begin{tabular}{c||c}
      Sistema       & $\delta W_{rev}$                   \\\hline\hline
      Hidrostático  & $-PdV$                             \\
      Elástico 1D   & $\tau dL$                          \\
      Laminas       & $\sigma dA$                        \\
      Dieléctricos  & $Ed\vec{P}$                        \\
      Paramagnético & $\underbrace{\mu_0H}_{B_0}\vec{M}$ \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabularcaption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It gives two errors: Missing number treated as zero and LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

Comment: @alvaritomendez - I experience no problems at all when I compile the code shown above.

Comment: @alvaritomendez just like Mico mentions, the code above compiles without error. If you get errors it's because of things you don't show in your (n)MWE. I'm afraid there's nothing we can do without further information. You could ask a follow-up question showing a minimal example of the your code in which you adapted the code from this answer that actually shows your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you load the [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package and enclose both the `tabular` environment and the `\caption` command in a `threeparttable` environment. That way, the width of the caption will be constrained to the width of the associated `tabular`-like environment.

Separately, I would also simplify the table's look by (a) getting rid of the double-struck vertical rule and (b) replacing the double-struck horizontal rule with a single, but well-spaced, horizontal rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage{threeparttable} % for 'threeparttable' environment
\usepackage{booktabs}       % for '\midrule' directive
\usepackage{array,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ l >{$}c<{$} } % automatic math mode in 2nd column
      Sistema       & \delta W_{\textup{rev}}  \\
      \midrule % <-- create a single, but well-spaced, horizontal rule
      Hidrostático  & -P\,dV                           \\
      Elástico 1D   & \tau\,dL                         \\
      Laminas       & \sigma\,dA                       \\
      Dieléctricos  & E\,d\vec{P}                      \\
      Paramagnético & \underbrace{\mu_0H}_{B_0}\vec{M} 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Trabajo reversible en diferentes sistemas}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which has a key `caption` for the caption. The caption is wrapped to the width of the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c||c}[caption = Trabajo reversible en diferentes sistemas]
      Sistema       & $\delta W_{rev}$                   \\\hline\hline
      Hidrostático  & $-PdV$                             \\
      Elástico 1D   & $\tau dL$                          \\
      Laminas       & $\sigma dA$                        \\
      Dieléctricos  & $Ed\vec{P}$                        \\
      Paramagnético & $\underbrace{\mu_0H}_{B_0}\vec{M}$ \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest a couple of changes. Regarding the rules and bars, it's possible to adjust double-line crossing with [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) and for instance make it hollow. Another option is to use single lines with different line thickness, in which case [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) package is required.

The [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) helps to format the caption, such that keep it left aligned in narrow environment or add a hanging indent (see the second table). More options are explain in [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption)

The `\xstrut` is to increase space between rules and the second row.

Table with double lines and hollow crossing

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}     % For !{\vrule ...}
\usepackage{caption}   % Caption formatting
\usepackage{hhline}    % Double line formatting

% Adds extra space in rows--required only in one cell 
\newcommand\xstrut[1][\baselineskip]{\rule[-0.3#1]{0pt}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \captionsetup{
        position=bottom,
        skip=3pt,
    }
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{c|| >{$}c<{$}}
          Sistema       & \delta W_{rev}                   \\\hhline{=::=}
          \xstrut[12pt]
          Hidrostático  & -PdV                             \\
          Elástico 1D   & \tau dL                          \\
          Laminas       & \sigma dA                        \\
          Dieléctricos  & Ed\vec{P}                        \\
          Paramagnético & \underbrace{\mu_0H}_{B_0}\vec{M}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Trabajo reversible en diferentes sistemas}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The table with single rules

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}     % For !{\vrule ...}
\usepackage{caption}   % Caption formatting

% Adds extra space in rows--required only in one cell 
\newcommand\xstrut[1][\baselineskip]{\rule[-0.3#1]{0pt}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \captionsetup{
        format=hang,
        justification=raggedright,
        position=bottom,
        skip=6pt,
    }
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{c !{\vrule width 0.4pt} >{$}c<{$}}
          Sistema       & \delta W_{rev}                   \\
          \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
          \xstrut[12pt]
          Hidrostático  & -PdV                             \\
          Elástico 1D   & \tau dL                          \\
          Laminas       & \sigma dA                        \\
          Dieléctricos  & Ed\vec{P}                        \\
          Paramagnético & \underbrace{\mu_0H}_{B_0}\vec{M}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Trabajo reversible en diferentes sistemas}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `talltblr` of `tabularray` package ((an exercise how to put caption below `talltblr` table and caption formatting by use of the `caption` package). Table design is adopted to my taste ;-) :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt,
                     font = {small, sf},
                     labelfont = bf,
                     justification=centerlast
                    }
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}%
{\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot,middlefoot}{default}{}  % <---
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{default}%               % <---
{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
}
\centering
    \begin{talltblr}[%
  theme = captionof,
caption = {Trabajo reversible en diferentes sistemas},
  label = {tblr:test}
              ]{colspec = {@{} r Q[l, mode=math] @{}}}
%
Sistema       & \delta W_{\mathrm{rev}}  \\
    \midrule % <-- create a single, but well-spaced, horizontal rule
Hidrostático  & -P\,dV                           \\
Elástico 1D   & \tau\,dL                         \\
Laminas       & \sigma\,dA                       \\
Dieléctricos  & E\,d\vec{P}                      \\
Paramagnético & \underbrace{\mu_0H}_{B_0}\vec{M}
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the r-l column layout.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much!